# Marshaling slice results in character string

Tags: arrays, json, go, marshalling

I'm trying to json encode a slice of `uint8` values, but doing so results in a character string. As an example, this:

```
d := []uint8{1,2,3,4}
data, err := json.Marshal(d)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Results in:

```
"AQIDBA==" <nil>
```

I was expecting  `[1,2,3,4]`, but I am getting this odd character string instead. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/BJfmzcV16r) is a playground with this code on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you use `uint8` type for your numbers, and `uint8` is an alias for `byte` ([Spec: Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)). And by default byte arrays and slices are encoded using Base64 encoding, that's what you see (`"AQIDBA=="` is the Base64 encoded text of the bytes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`).

Quoting from [`json.Marhsal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) doc:

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string, and a nil slice encodes as the null JSON object.

Change your number type for `uint` or `int` for example, and then you will see what you expect.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hQyXV_e5nc)):

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Data []uint
}

d := new(MyStruct)
d.Data = []uint{1, 2, 3, 4}

data, err := json.Marshal(d)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Output:

```
{"Data":[1,2,3,4]} <nil>
```